# CentOS PHP Sessions not working even though the PHP Info page says it is

Tags: linux, centos

I have PHP installed properly from the Remi repo on CentOS 6 (64 bit).

[image]

As shown in the image above, the PHP information page shows sessions as working and installed, yet I get this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_create() in /var/www/lighttpd/index.php on line 1`

I've tried multiple reinstalls, different PHP RPM's, and yet nothing will get sessions going. How can I get PHP sessions working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). "session_create()" is a phpBB function.

Comment: Haha, oops! I got another error message once I changed to _start(): `Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_k00cap6jt0ktu52k1ui3qdi7c7, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/lighttpd/index.php on line 1 bool(true) Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_k00cap6jt0ktu52k1ui3qdi7c7, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0` -  but this should be easy to fix - thanks!